# How to scale a number on 1-100 scale

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R which has following values

```
  count      Score
    2         99 
   89         91
   124        87
   670        70
   2111       10
   34         97
```

and so on. `largest number is 2111 and smallest is 2` Now,I want to get those number on 1-100 scale. Smallest being 100 and largest being 1

I have put in some approximate values in `Score` column. How can we do it in R

Comment: You may check `?scale`.  Are you saying thaat `Score` is the expected output?  Perhaps `scales::rescale(-df1$count, to = c(1, 100))`

Comment: `100*count/max(count)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rescale`

```
round(scales::rescale(-df1$count, to = c(1, 100)))
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly it does? I mean methodology to scale it?

Comment: @Neil I multiplied by negative and specified the range `to` as 1, 100.  Instead you can keep the original value can change `to = c(100, 1)`

Comment: Ok. I want it `c(1,100)` Thanks for your answer. What if I do `round(scales::rescale(df1$count, to = c(1, 100))`

Comment: @Neil I meant `round(scales::rescale(df1$count, to = c(100, 1)))`  If you do it in the reverse ie. c(1, 100), the highest value will be 100 and lowest 1

Comment: Got it. Thanks a ton. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
1 + 99 * (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

Comment: You may apply `round` if you want integers? To reverse it, try... er... `101 - y` where `y` is the above result.

Answer (score 1):

I know @Friday has given the best answer. But this should work too.

```
ord <- order(counts)
pc <- seq(1, 100, length.out = length(counts))
model <- lm(pc ~ counts[ord])
new_counts <- predict(model)[ord]
```